# Django migrate won't update my database

Tags: django, django-migrations

Starting from an existing database, I want to update it schema. I change one of my models, then run

```
python manage.py makemigrations myapp
```

which creates the migration, defining the new tables and columns correctly. Sample output:

```
Migrations for 'myapp':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Foo
    - Add field Bar
    - ...
```

Then I apply the migration:

```
python manage.py migrate --database mydb
```

I get this output:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, myapp, contenttypes, sessions, auth
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
```

It seems to have worked. Git tells me that the sqlite file corresponding to "mydb" has changed. However, instead of having my new tables and columns inside, it just erased the content, leaving empty tables with the old schema.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: try: `python manage.py migrate myapp`

Comment: By default it will try to apply every possible migration (there is only one in my case).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a legacy database without migrations applied you should create `initial migrations` without any changes. That means that if you changed "models.py" revert it to its original state, then run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations myapp
```

Then run "fake" migrations

```
python manage.py migrate --database mydb --fake-initial
```

After that you can modify your "models.py" and use the normal migrations.

Comment: I did that `--fake-initial` as you suggest, and I get the same output as above. After that, `python manage.py migrate [myapp] --database mydb` tells me "No migrations to apply". And my tables are empty with the old schema.

Comment: Did you remove all `Alter field` and `add field` commands from `0001_initial.py`?

Comment: No, should I ? Actually with --fake-initial the tables are no more empty. I don't know what changed in it that Git detects.

Comment: Django stores every done migration in the database too. That's probably what Git detects. If you start using migrations in your database you should create "pure" migrations files resembling the stage of your database (no model changes). Then "fake" these migrations. Now you can change your models and do normal migrations.

Comment: So I have to revert my models.py, then fake it, then change the model, then migrate, right ?

Comment: Yes. And probably you also have to delete the entry in the `django_migrations` table.

Comment: It worked, thanks ! No need to remove the `django_migrations` entry. I totally despise this migration system.